# MongoDB 3.2.1 Java BasicDBObjectBuilder

Tags: java, mongodb

I am getting the following Error when I tried to insert BasicDBObjectBuilder into collection

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "xxx.xxx.x.x" , 27017 );
    MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("hello"); //create database

    MongoCollection<BasicDBObjectBuilder> collbuild = db.getCollection("newcoll", BasicDBObjectBuilder.class);
    BasicDBObjectBuilder collbuilder =  BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("name","joe")
            .add("dob", "12/12/12")
            .add("country", "Utopia");
    collbuild.insertOne((BasicDBObjectBuilder) collbuilder.get()); // passing BasicDBObjectBuilder into a BasicDBObjectBuilder collection?
```

I thought I am passing the BasicDBObjectBuilder into a BasicDBObjectBuilder collection. I know how to use BasicDBObject but I want to try this method because I am new to programming. So can someone clarify?

> UPDATED

It seems I was trying to to use insertOne which is a BasicDBObject function. So what is needed to pass the BasicDBObjectBuilder into a BasicDBObjectBuilder collection?

Comment: BasicDBObjectBuilder  is itself a builder of DBObject  types . Why would you want to add BasicDBObjectBuilder  into a BasicDBObjectBuilder ?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-insert-a-document/ I am trying to use insertOne but it seems I get a codec error because BasicDBObjectBuilder  is not in the driver

Comment: Is creating a collection with this MongoCollection<BasicDBObjectBuilder> collbuild = db.getCollection("newcoll", BasicDBObjectBuilder.class); or MongoCollection<BasicDBObject> coll = db.getCollection("mycoll", BasicDBObject.class); Which one is correct ? or both is fine?